# Images from my AWS Bucket not showing on my website

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I've implemented AWS S3 storage to my Django project. So I just uploaded all my static images to my bucket. However it is not showing up on my site. My HTML for the images are the standard Django syntax for template:

```
<img src="{% static 'images/settingsIcon.png' %}">
```

The `img` `src` appears to point to the correct URL (the image in my bucket):

[image]

however the image still doesn't work. Any idea why?

Comment: Because your image is set to private and the link you pasted into your `src` has already expired (since it is a temporary one). Read up on your bucket permissions.

Comment: Is this what takes it off private so it can show up?: https://i.imgur.com/HkwJnve.png, https://i.imgur.com/tWsJwe7.png

Comment: I don't know. I don't use `AWS` but probably.

Comment: This url - http://postr-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/settingsIcon.png?Expires=1519207755&AccessKeyId=AKIAID03PF5Y7SMSOHHA - is working for me. Did you change the perminssions?

Comment: Ah when I double click on that `src` in the `<img>`, the URL is actually this: `https://postr-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/settingsIcon.png?AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDO3PF5Y7SMSOHHA&Expires=1519213791&Signature=gi3TNIJAaY%2FK%2FPkARy908e01%2FIw%3D` and not `http://postr-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/settingsIcon.png?Expires=1519207755&AccessKeyId=AKIAID03PF5Y7SMSOHHA`. Any idea?

Answer (score 1):

You need to change Content-Type of the uploaded file  'ContentType' =>'image/jpeg'.
And, also you need to turn off Block public access.

```
const uploadFile = new aws.S3.ManagedUpload({
        params: {
          ...uploadParams,
          ContentType: 'image/jpeg',
          Key: file.name,
          Body: fileUploadStream,
        },
      });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add this in your `settings.py` file:

```
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = False
```

Answer (score 0):

Add the below in `settings.py` file

`AWS_S3_ADDRESSING_STYLE = "virtual"`