# Clicking 'Make public' on my S3 Bucket doesn't do anything

Tags: python, django, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

Here is the image of me clicking 'Make Public' on one of my images in my bucket:

[image]

and then subsequently clicking 'Make public' on the pop-up window:

[image]

It says it completed successfully - however when I refresh the page it still gives me the option to 'Make public' so it appears it didn't work. When I go to my website the image still doesn't show up, further showing the image is still not public. This is the `src` the `img` uses on my website:

```
https://postr-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/settingsIcon.png?Expires=1519249290&Signature=9eixuWMxLknf%2BAnDB1XIS30ntO8%3D&AWSAccessKeyId=AKIAIDO3PF5Y7SMSOHHA
```

I don't think the access key should be in that `src`, but I'm not sure how to change it. My settings for AWS are normal:

```
from decouple import config
import datetime
AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID = config("AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID")
AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY = config("AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY")
AWS_FILE_EXPIRE = 200
AWS_PRELOAD_METADATA = True
AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH = True

DEFAULT_FILE_STORAGE = 'draft1.aws.utils.MediaRootS3BotoStorage'
STATICFILES_STORAGE = 'draft1.aws.utils.StaticRootS3BotoStorage'
AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME = 'postr-bucket'
S3DIRECT_REGION = 'us-west-2'
S3_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_URL = '//%s.s3.amazonaws.com/media/' % AWS_STORAGE_BUCKET_NAME
MEDIA_ROOT = MEDIA_URL
STATIC_URL = S3_URL + 'static/'
ADMIN_MEDIA_PREFIX = STATIC_URL + 'admin/'

two_months = datetime.timedelta(days=61)
date_two_months_later = datetime.date.today() + two_months
expires = date_two_months_later.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y 20:00:00 GMT")

AWS_HEADERS = { 
    'Expires': expires,
    'Cache-Control': 'max-age=%d' % (int(two_months.total_seconds()), ),
}
```

I've also tried the same 'Make public' option for the whole bucket, however it has the same result (says success but it doesn't make it public).

Any idea why this is?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You are making it too complicated - since you made it public, the src should be

https://postr-bucket.s3.amazonaws.com/static/images/settingsIcon.png

you can forget the rest of the parameters, they are probably causing it too fail - if you click the link I gave you, you will see your image - I know I can.

Edit: see this link: https://django-storages.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/amazon-S3.html

```
    AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH (optional; default is True)
    Setting AWS_QUERYSTRING_AUTH to False to remove query parameter authentication from generated URLs. 
    This can be useful if your S3 buckets are public.
```

Comment: Yes that's what it should be but i don't directly write the `src`, it's generated by `src={% static 'images/settingsIcon.png' %}`

Comment: @Zorgan you appear to be trying to do this as a workaround to [your real problem](https://stackoverflow.com/q/48901990/1695906).  It would be advisable not to try to solve this by making the image public, and it isn't going to work with a public image if the credentials are somehow causing the problem.

Comment: @Michael-sqlbot Making the image public is meant to be the solution to my other question. Unless there is another way?

Comment: I believe you got some bad advice on the other question.  The reason for the Signature and other parameters is so that you do *not* need to make the bucket or the objects public.

Comment: Right. Any idea how I can fix it?

Answer (score 0):

Have you try making your file public via API with `.set_canned_acl('public-read')`?

```
    import boto
    import boto.s3.connection
    from boto.s3.key import Key 

    conn = boto.connect_s3(
        aws_access_key_id = <access_key>,
        aws_secret_access_key = <secret_key>,
        host = <host>,
        calling_format = boto.s3.connection.OrdinaryCallingFormat(),
    )

    bucket = conn.get_bucket(<bucket name>, validate=False)
    k = Key(bucket)
    k.key = <filename>
    k.set_contents_from_filename(<filename>)

    hello_key = bucket.get_key(<filename>)
    hello_key.set_canned_acl('public-read')
```